# How to finish/trim prefab fireplace

Tags: tile, fireplace

We demoed a 70's stone fireplace and re-framed where we had a lot of rot. I'm planning to buy or build a surround/mantle and incorporate some stone or tile in the end.

I'm wondering what the next step should be. Should I put durock right up against the black face of this prefab fireplace? Or can I put mastic and tile right up against this? I'm concerned obviously because of the heat. Or do I need to buy some kind of a metal prefab trim/surround type thing? There were brass doors there before that we removed and threw away. I just don't know anything about prefab fireplaces and finishing them.

[image: fireplace]

Comment: Gas fireplace? It matters. Did you maintain the required clearance to your wood above the fireplace?

Answer (score 1):

Each fireplace manufacturer has specific clearances and installation instructions. If you don’t know the brand, I’d get an installation manual like this one, and study it.

http://www.kozyheat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Z42-Z42CD-Manual-1-09.pdf

Also, I’d be concerned about the styrofoam exposed to the fireplace box. The fireplace gives off a lot of heat and it could affect the styrofoam.

Also, if you use tile or rock to cover the face of the fireplace, use “fire resistant” type mortar, grout, etc. Otherwise, when the mortar/grout gets hot, it could all sag.